# Heap memory error with bulkwrite in Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, bulkinsert

I'm struggling with the bulkWrite operation. I'm dealing with 100,000 data. The below code works fine for 40k data. I am having memory issues if I try to save more than 50k data.

I tried insertMany(), it failed for 20k data. What would be the efficient method to upsert 100,000 data?

Code:

```
async bulkInsertData(array) {
      const options = [];
      await sleep(60000);
      for (const item of array) {
        options.push({
          updateOne: {
            filter: { "id": item.id },
            update: {
              "$set": 
              {
                caseType : item.caseType,
                category : item.category
              }
            },
            upsert: true
          }
        })
      };
      await sleep(60000);
      const result = await this.dataModel.bulkWrite(options , { ordered: false })
      console.log(result)          
    }
```

Error

```
 <--- Last few GCs --->

[22:0x5f968d0]  1896003 ms: Mark-sweep 502.2 (519.2) -> 498.4 (518.9) MB, 435.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.158, current mu = 0.051) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

[22:0x5f968d0]  1896424 ms: Mark-sweep 502.4 (518.9) -> 498.7 (519.9) MB, 392.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.117, current mu = 0.067) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: Try to update nodejs version.

Comment: I'm using Nest 8.0.0. This error occurs in Heroku which runs uses 2x dyno. I'm looking for the possible ways to improve the code

Comment: But why use `bulkWrite`? I had similar issue before and resolve it by inserting row by row with for loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Javascript/Node js expert, so my code below might not be syntactically correct, but I can see that the problem is that you are trying to keep thousands of queries in memory simultaneously. If instead you build only a limited number of queries at a time(say 500), perform the updates, clear the queries array and then process the next 500 records, you wouldn't run out of memory

```js
async bulkInsertData(array) {
      var options = [];
      var result;

      await sleep(60000);
      for (const item of array) {
        options.push({
          updateOne: {
            filter: { "id": item.id },
            update: {
              "$set": 
              {
                caseType : item.caseType,
                category : item.category
              }
            },
            upsert: true
          }
        })
        
        if(options.length === 500) {
           result = await this.dataModel.bulkWrite(options , { ordered: false })
           console.log(result)
           options = [] // Clear queries array
        }
      };
      await sleep(60000);    

      // For the last batch
      if(options.length > 0) {
           result = await this.dataModel.bulkWrite(options , { ordered: false });
           console.log(result);
      }      
}
```

Comment: This code is basically pushing only one element into the options array at a time and wouldn't enter either of the if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your situation. In my personal experiences, I have tried several different approach.

1. Simply update the NodeJS usage memory size by setting `--max-old-space-size=SIZE`. You can consult the doc https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--max-old-space-sizesize-in-megabytes. You can try and error to find the suitable limitation.
2. Like @devatherock suggested, you should try to batch your insert.
3. Try to use mongo-native driver(https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) instead of mongoose. mongoose is good ORM tool but the memory size would be lot more bigger. If you want to insert tons of data, try to use native driver and direct insert into database.